# Finding the Closest Pair of Points Using basic functions

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, closest-points

I'm tryin' to find the closest pair of points, but my code just won't work. I'm not expert in this field, please help me out. This is for my project T_T

my code goes like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FindingClosestPair {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the number of points: ");
        int nPoints = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter "+nPoints+" points: ");
        float [][] points = new float [nPoints][2];
        for(int r=0; r<points.length; r++){
            for(int c=0; c<points[0].length; c++){
                points[r][c] = input.nextFloat(); 
            }
        }

        for(int r=0; r<points.length; r++){
            for(float e : points[r]){
                System.out.print(e+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        float p1=0, p2=0, shortestDistance=0, d1=0, d2=0, d=0;
        float x1=0, x2 = 0, x3=0, y1=0, y2 = 0, y3=0;
        float a1=0, a2=0, b1=0, b2=0;

        for(int r1=0; r1<points.length-2; r1++){
            x1 = points[r1][0];
            y1 = points[r1][1];
            for(int r2=r1+1; r2<points.length-1; r2++){
                x2 = points[r2][0];
                y2 = points[r2][1];
                d1 = (float) Math.sqrt((Math.pow(x2-x1, 2))+(Math.pow(y2-y1, 2)));
                for(int r3=r2+1; r3<points.length; r3++){
                    x3 = points[r3][0];
                    y3 = points[r3][1];
                    d2 = (float) Math.sqrt((Math.pow(x3-x1, 2))+(Math.pow(y3-y1, 2)));
                    if(d1<d2){
                        d=d1;
                        a1=x1; b1=y1;
                        a2=x2; b2=y2;
                    }else if(d2<d1){
                        d=d2;
                        a1=x1; b1=y1;
                        a2=x3; b2=y3;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The closest two points are ("+a1+","+b1+") and ("+a2+","+b2+")");
    }
}
```

So there. I'm pretty bad, right? T_T

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it work with one loop less? pseudo code written in browser:

```
int clostestPointA = 0;
int clostestPointB = 1;
float closestDist = float.MAX_VALUE;

for(int pointA=0; pointA<points.length-1; pointA++){
    xA = points[pointA][0];
    yA = points[pointA][1];
    for(int pointB=pointA+1; pointB<points.length; pointB++){
        xB = points[pointB][0];
        yB = points[pointB][1];
        d1 = Math.pow(xA-xB, 2) + Math.pow(yA-yB, 2); //dist squared, squareroots are slow and not needed for the comparison
        if(d1 < closestDist){
            //set clostestPointA and clostestPointB
            closestPointA = pointA;
            closestPointB = pointB;
            closestDist = d1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Except loops are iterating one time too few. Outer loop should be `-1` and inner loop should be to end of array.

Comment: thank you for your comments and suggestions. i just got the correct code ^^